# Get versionCode and versionName from Manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a script that automatically increases **versionName** and **versionCode** in the **Manifest.xml**. Android studio uses the **versionName** and **versionCode** from **build.gradle.**

*build.gradle*:

```
task('increaseVersionCode') << {
def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
matcher.find()
def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + ++versionCode + "\"")
manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

task('incrementVersionName') << {
def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
matcherVersionNumber.find()
def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
def pointVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
def buildVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(4))
def mNextVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + pointVersion + "." + (buildVersion + 1)
def manifestContent = matcherVersionNumber.replaceAll("versionName=\"" + mNextVersionName + "\"")
manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig' || task.name == 'generateDebugBuildConfig') {
    task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
    task.dependsOn 'incrementVersionName'
    }
}
```

How do i get the versionCode from manifest into build.gradle?

Comment: But you can set the app version code/name directly in gradle in android -> buildConfig under the build.gradle file .. and you can remove the ones from the manifest file

Comment: @Cata But i need it to increase the code and number automatically.

Comment: Agreed. This approach has been obsolete since at least summer of 2014. Here is a sample project that demonstrates automatically incrementing the `versionCode`, without messing with the manifest: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Gradle/HelloVersioning/build.gradle Similar approaches exist for dynamically modifying `versionName`, or generating it from the `versionCode`, or generating both from a common set of values (e.g., major/minor/patchlevel).